# Compare 2 lists for partial match

Tags: c#, list, string-comparison, partial-matches

**C# Folks!**  I have 2 List that I want to compare.

**Example**:

```
List<string> ONE contains:
A
B
C

List<string> TWO contains:
B
C
```

I know I can achieve the results of ONE if I do:

```
ONE.Except(TWO);
```

**Results**:  A

---

> How can I do the same if my Lists contain a file extension for each
>   Element?

---

```
List<string> ONE contains:
A.pdf
B.pdf
C.pdf

List<string> TWO contains: (will always have .txt extension)
B.txt
C.txt
```

Results should = A.pdf

I realized that I need to display the full filename (A.pdf) in a report at the end, so I cannot strip the extension, like I originally did.

*Thanks for the help!*

**EDIT**:
This is how I went about it, but I am not sure if this is the "best" or "most performant" way to actually solve it, but it does seem to work...

```
foreach (string s in ONE)
{
     //since I know TWO will always be .txt
     string temp = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(s) + ".txt";

     if (TWO.Contains(temp))
     {
          // yes it exists, do something
     }
     else
     {
          // no it does not exist, do something
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This a very straightforward and a easy code , but if your requirement has more file extension

```
    List<string> lstA = new List<string>() { "A.pdf", "B.pdf", "C.pdf" };

        List<string> lstB = new List<string>() { "B.txt", "C.txt" };

        foreach (var item in lstA)
        {
            if (lstB.Contains(item.Replace(".pdf",".txt"))==false)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks!  I appreciate the help and suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

You can implement a custom equality comparer:

```
class FileNameComparer: IEqualityComparer<String>
{
    public bool Equals(String b1, String b2)
    {
        return Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(b1).Equals(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(b2));
    }

    public int GetHashCode(String a)
    {
        return Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(a).GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

... and pass it to the Except method:

```
System.Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", list1.Except(list2, new FileNameComparer())));
```

Comment: Thank you!  I appreciate the help.  You used some things that I am not yet familiar with, but it looks simplistic (a good thing).